# macOS: How to force hibernate, shut down, and restore

Tags: macos, bootcamp, shutdown, restart, hibernate

I want to

1. Write the current state of macOS to `/private/var/vm/sleepimage` immediately before shutting down
2. Power on my Mac again and boot into my Boot Camp Windows partition (by holding <kbd>opt</kbd> at boot) and do some tasks
3. Shut down and power on again (selecting macOS at boot) and **load the saved state from my sleep image to resume EXACTLY as I left it after writing the image**

How can I achieve this?

OS/hardware config:
macOS 10.13.2 on a MacBook Pro 11,3 (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Harv To resume exactly where I left off

Comment: You're asking for the machine NOT to do what you're asking it to do (shut down) - nope, that's not going to happen. What you might want to consider is running Windows in a VM, instead. There's too much complexity in saving the state EXACTLY as you want it, otherwise we'd be doing that (and are headed in that direction I believe). iOS is an example of where they're playing with that. macOS is going there too, which is partially why it's been so unstable lately; they're rewriting very large parts of it.

Comment: @Harv VM won’t work because I need 100% hardware utilization. Now if I could run macOS, Linux, and Windows on a type-1 hypervisor on my MBP then I’d say absolutely.